# Moving items between two hashtables

Tags: c, hashtable

I am trying to make a program that inserts and removes items from a hashtable I made (the hashtable is working just fine). The program has a main menu, and it will call the `insert` and `delete` functions given the right input.

The program consists in 2 hashtables:

- `active_users` hashtable
- `inactive_users` hashtable

When an user is "deleted" it moves the user from the active users hashtable to the inactive users hashtable.

**The problem:**
To move the user from the active hashtable to the inactive I first get the user info from the active hashtable, and insert it in the inactive hashtable. I then delete it from the active hashtable. However, for some reason  its also removing from the inactive hashtable, causing the error.

**Note:** The functions `insert2`, `delete_item` and `contains` are all hashtable functions that are called to perform the operations within the hashtable. These functions all work well, so I don't think the problem is from the hashtable implementation.

```
typedef struct user{
    char nick[6];
    char name[26];
    bool occupied;
}user; 

void insert_user(hashtable *active_users, hashtable *inactive_users, char *input_a, char *input_b){
    user *new_user = malloc(sizeof(user)); //initializes a new user
    strcpy(new_user->name, input_b);
    strcpy(new_user->nick, input_a);
    new_user->occupied = true;
    if(contains(active_users, input_a) == -1 && contains(inactive_users, input_a) == -1){
        if(load_factor(active_users)){ //checks the size of the hashtable
            resize_HashTable(active_users); // if true, resizes
        }
        insert2(active_users, new_user); //insert user in actives
        printf("+ user %s created\n", input_a);
    }else{
        printf("+ nick %s already used\n", input_a);
    }
}  

void delete_user(hashtable *active_users, hashtable *inactive_users, char *input_a){
    if(contains(active_users, input_a) != -1){
        user *tmp = get_item(active_users, input_a); //get the user from active
        insert2(inactive_users, tmp); //insert in inactives
        delete_item(active_users, input_a); //delete from active
        printf("+ user %s removed\n", input_a);
    }else{
        printf("+ user %s doesnt exist\n", input_a);
    }
}

int main(){
    hashtable *active_users = create();
    hashtable *inactive_users = create();
    char buffer[37];
    char tipo;
    char input_a[6];
    char input_b[26];
    while(fgets(buffer, 37, stdin)){
        sscanf(buffer, "%c %s %[^\n]s", &tipo, input_a, input_b);
        switch(tipo) {
            case 'U' :
                insert_user(active_users, inactive_users, input_a, input_b);
                break;
            case 'R' :
                delete_user(active_users, inactive_users, input_a);
                break;
            default :
                printf("Invalid Operation\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As request the hashtable functions:

```
void insert2(hashtable *HashTable, user *a){
    int hash_value = hash(a->nick);
    int new_position = hash_value % HashTable->size;
    if (new_position < 0) new_position += HashTable->size;
    int position = new_position;
    while (HashTable->buckets[position]->occupied && position != new_position - 1) {
        position++;
        position %= HashTable->size;
    }
    a->occupied = true;
    HashTable->buckets[position] = a;
    HashTable->elements++;
}

void delete_item(hashtable *HashTable, char *nick){
    int position = contains(HashTable, nick);
    if(position != -1){
        HashTable->buckets[position]->occupied = false;
    }
    HashTable->elements--;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Based on your description, you have hash maps where you have pointers to the data rather than the data itself in the hash table.  So if you free the data (is that what delete_item does?), then it will delete the data pointed to by both maps.  Instead, just remove the reference to the data in the hash map that it is being removed from rather than freeing the memory pointed to by it.

Comment: You say that you know your hashtable implementation works, but you don't say *how* you know that so we have to assume you're wrong. We need to see more detail - in particular, details of the semantics of your `get`, `insert`, and `delete` operations.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons every user as the variable "occupied" set to true when they are created, and when the delete function of the hashtable is called it simple finds the user and marks the "occupied" variable to false, making its position available to be used again by the insert function

Comment: @MDordio If such is the case, the point remains.  If you are dealing in pointers, then setting the `occupied` struct var will affect both hashmaps as they are pointing to the same memory location.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons but when i create the 2 hashtables i am creating 2 different ones, right? if so how can i call a function to one of them and affecting the other?

Comment: Note: the final `s` in `"%c %s %[^\n]s"` is not needed.

Comment: @MDordio If you are dealing with pointers, then you can have pointers in the two hash tables pointing to the same location of memory.  When you change the data stored in that location, it will be seen by everything that points to that location of memory.

Comment: You leak memory in insert when `nick %s already used`: you neither use nor free `new_user`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons so you are saying the problem is in the hashtable implementation(in the delete function?) and not in the code i showed above?

Comment: Show us `delete_item` and `insert2`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie i updated the question, with those functions

Comment: `delete_user` and `insert_user` are actually just the same function and should be replaced with one function `move_user(table_from, table_to)`, where a user is created if it doesn't exist in the hash table "to".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are a few observations. I think you should seriously redesign your code. In my opinion you should have just one function `move_user` that moves the user from one table to the other and sets the bucket it occupied to null (and so remove the `occupied` flag from the `user` struct, whch doesn't belong there):

In `insert2` you add an element even it is already there (you don't check for that).

In `delete_item` you decrement the number of elements even if the element was not found.

In `insert2` you overwrite an existing item and so you leak memory.

In `insert2` you don't check if there is an element in a bucket. The check
 `while (HashTable->buckets[position]->occupied` can thus cause a seg fault if the bucket is null.

---

As to the problem you report: when you do 
`user *tmp = get_item(active_users, input_a);` you get a pointer to the user. You then insert this record pointed to in the inactive hash table and "remove" it from the active hash table. However, your "removing" is just setting the occupied flag *in the user record* to zero, so it now will neither be found in the other hash table. As said above, this flag doesn't belong in the user data struct.

Comment: so, to remove the "occupied" from the user struct should i then make a struck "bucket" that contains a pointer to the struct user(to store the user info) and a bool occupied? and the hashtable struct will consist in struct with bucket **buckets, what do you think?

Comment: A bucket of your hash tables contains a pointer to a user. If the bucket is not occupied it is `NULL`. When you move a user between tables, you move this pointer and set the bucket it occupied to `NULL`.No need for flags.